# JOOQ arrayAgg array_agg fields as object

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have 2 entities:

```
record Customer(String name, List<CustomerContact > contactHistory) {}

record CustomerContact(LocalDateTime contactAt, Contact.Type type) {
  public enum Type {
    TEXT_MESSAGE, EMAIL
  }
}
```

These are persisted in a schema with 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
  "id".   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name"  TEXT      NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customer_contact(
  "customer_id" BIGINT REFERENCES "customer" (ID) NOT NULL,
  "type"        TEXT                           NOT NULL,
  "contact_at"  TIMESTAMPTZ                    NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'utc')
);
```

I want to retrieve the details of my Customers with a single query, and use the `arrayAgg` method to add the contactHistory to each customer. I have a query like this:

```java
//pseudo code

DSL.select(field("customer.name"))
   .select(arrayAgg(field("customer_contact.contact_at")) //TODO How to aggregate both fields into a CustomerContact object
   .from(table("customer"))
   .join(table("customer_contact")).on(field("customer_contact.customer_id").eq("customer.id"))
   .groupBy(field("customer_contact.customer_id"))
   .fetchOptional()
   .map(asCustomer());
```

The problem I have with this is that `arrayAgg` will only work with a single field. I want to use 2 fields, and bind them into a single object (`CustomerContact`) then use that as the basis for the `arrayAgg`

Apologies if I have not explained this clearly! Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using [`ARRAY_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/array-agg-function/), how about using the much more powerful [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) or [`MULTISET`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) to get the most out of jOOQ's type safe capabilities? Combine that with [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) for type safe mapping to your Java records, [as shown also in this article](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/). Your query would then look like this:

#### Using `MULTISET_AGG`

```java
List<Customer> customers =
ctx.select(
        CUSTOMER.NAME,
        multisetAgg(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CONTACT_AT, CUSTOMER_CONTACT.TYPE)
            .convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(CustomerContact::new))))
   .from(CUSTOMER)
   .join(CUSTOMER_CONTACT).on(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CUSTOMER_ID.eq(CUSTOMER.ID))
   .groupBy(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CUSTOMER_ID)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Customer::new));
```

Note that the entire query type checks. If you change anything about the query or about your records, it won't compile anymore, giving you additional type safety. This is assuming that youre `Type` enum is either:

- Generated from a PostgreSQL `ENUM` type
- Converted automatically using an [enum converter, attached to generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-enum-converter/)

Depending on your tastes, using [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) could slightly simplify the query for you?

```java
List<Customer> customers =
ctx.select(
        CUSTOMER_CONTACT.customer().NAME,
        multisetAgg(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CONTACT_AT, CUSTOMER_CONTACT.TYPE)
            .convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(CustomerContact::new))))
   .from(CUSTOMER_CONTACT)
   .groupBy(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CUSTOMER_ID)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Customer::new));
```

It's not a big deal in this query, but in a more complex query, it can reduce complexity.

#### Using `MULTISET`

An alterantive is to nest your query instead of aggregating, like this:

```java
List<Customer> customers =
ctx.select(
        CUSTOMER.NAME,
        multiset(
            select(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CONTACT_AT, CUSTOMER_CONTACT.TYPE)
            .from(CUSTOMER_CONTACT)
            .where(CUSTOMER_CONTACT.CUSTOMER_ID.eq(CUSTOMER.ID))
        ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(CustomerContact::new))))
   .from(CUSTOMER)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Customer::new));
```

#### Code generation

For this answer, I was assuming you're using the code generator ([you should!](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)), as it would greatly contribute to this code being type safe, and make this answer more readable.

Much of the above can be done without code generation (except implicit joins), but I'm sure this answer could nicely demonstrate the benefits it terms of type safety.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These multiset methods are only available with JOOQ 3.15+? I think we're using 3.14 unfortunately.

Comment: @robjwilkins: Time to upgrade

Comment: Think we're restricted due to Springboot not supporting Jooq above v3.14? Possible to get this working by calling the `multiset` using the Jooq `function` method?

Comment: @robjwilkins: Spring Boot does not restrict you in any way from this upgrade! You can't get my answer to work on jOOQ 3.14, this is a massive new feature from jOOQ 3.15.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrade is not an options, one way to do this is:

using the .arrayAgg(field()) but instead of "customer_contact.contact_at" use json_build_object as in

```html
arrayAgg(field(fieldsToJson(customer_contact.contact_at, customer_contact.FIELD_TWO))).as(CUSTOMER_CONTACT_LIST))
```

```java
    private String fieldsToJson(List<TableField<?,?>> fields) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("json_build_object(");
        for (Field<?> field : fields) {
            sb.append("'").append(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, field.getName())).append("'").append(",").append(field).append(",");
        }
        sb.replace(sb.length() - 1, sb.length(), ")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Then in your mapper use an ObjectMapper in turn the JSON into your CustomerContact object.

```html
Object[] contacts = record.get(CUSTOMER_CONTACT_LIST, Object[].class);
```

then for each:

```html
objectMapper.readValue(contactObject.toString(), CustomerContact.class);
```